# Access Zipform plus feature through Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I have zipform plus account as well Docusign account. I have also integrated zipform plus with Docusign.

Below are my questions:

1. How to access Transaction of zipform plus with Docusign API
2. Inside any Transaction detail we have some tabs like Parties, Property and Documents.

How to access these features of Transaction with Docusign API especially Parties and Property?

When I upload any document and finishes the esign step, after that it is reflecting in Docusign portal but vice versa is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but your question is not clear enough to give a useful answer. Your question is too general...what have you tried that is working or not working?

You say:

> I have also integrated zipform plus with Docusign.

Who wrote the integration software? You need to ask that person your questions.

Or are you trying to write the integration software?

Comment: Sorry for previous comment. Is there any API for zipform plus?. And Integration means I HAVE SET UP MY DOCUSIGN CREDENTIALS IN ZIPFORM PLUS with the help of this [link](https://support.docusign.com/articles/How-do-I-set-up-my-DocuSign-credentials-in-zipForm-Plus)

Comment: You will need to contact zip form plus customer service to get their help with their product.